In Apple Healthkit, Workout totalEnergyBurned is deprecated but active energy returns null
I am trying to get the total calories burned for a workout. In the below example, deprecatedCalories which uses sample.totalEnergyBurned returns the correct number of calories, but it tells me that it is deprecated and I should use .statistics to retrieve information about the workout instead. So I did that with the calories variable.
However, sample.statistics(for: quantityType)? returns nil, while the deprecated code returns the correct amount. As far as I can tell, there is no other quantity type I can use besides HKQuantityType(.activeEnergyBurned). Is this something not achievable in Swift right now with .statistics(), or is there another way to retrieve totalEnergyBurned per workout which is not be deprecated?
class HealthKitManager:ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var exercises:[Exercise] = []
    
    var healthStore: HKHealthStore
    var queryAnchorExercise: HKQueryAnchor?
    var queryExercise: HKAnchoredObjectQuery?

    init() {
        if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            healthStore = HKHealthStore()
        } else {
            fatalError("Health data not available")
        }

        initExerciseQuery()
    }

    func initExerciseQuery() {
        
        self.queryExercise = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(
            type: HKWorkoutType.workoutType(),
            predicate: healthLastDayPredicate(),
            anchor: queryAnchorExercise,
            limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit,
            resultsHandler: exerciseUpdateHandler
        )
        
        self.queryExercise!.updateHandler = self.exerciseUpdateHandler
            
        healthStore.execute(self.queryExercise!)
        
    }
    
    func exerciseUpdateHandler(query: HKAnchoredObjectQuery, newSamples: [HKSample]?, deleteSamples: [HKDeletedObject]?, newAnchor: HKQueryAnchor?, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Health query error \(error)")
        } else {
            if let newSamples = newSamples as? [HKWorkout], !newSamples.isEmpty {
                for sample in newSamples {
                    let quantityType = HKQuantityType(.activeEnergyBurned)
                    let calories = sample.statistics(for: quantityType)?
                    let deprecatedCalories = sample.totalEnergyBurned?
                }
            }

            if let anchor = newAnchor {
                self.queryAnchorExercise = anchor
            }
        }
    }
}


I had the same problem and I think what you'd need is to use QueryDescriptor.
Here is an example for sample query.
    let desc = HKSampleQueryDescriptor(
    predicates: [.workout(todayPredicate)],
    sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.endDate, order: .reverse)],
    )
    let sources = try? await desc.result(for: store)
    if let sources = sources {
        for source in sources {
            let stat = source.statistics(for: 
            HKQuantityType(.activeEnergyBurned))
            print("\(stat?.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for:.kilocalorie()).rounded())")
        }

    private func makeTodayPredicate() {
    let startDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
    let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)
    todayPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate)
}

